# Batching in foreach or foreach partition in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We reading a file with huge number of rows. After reading we need to make a cache call for foreach row. The cache support batch gets with maximum of 30 records. So how to group data within foreach/foreach partition to pick 30 elements at a time to make cache call. There is some grouped() function available in scala. I am looking for something similar in java.

One way is to do Iterators.partition(). Trying to understand if there is any way spark standard way of doing it.

Comment: Spark streaming batches by time, not sure if you can batch by records

Comment: This is a batch job not streaming job.

Comment: Okay, then I'm removing the tag

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use your cache! 30 records at a time is not scalable. 
I would recommend to load your cache into a dataframe and cache this dataframe, if possible.
i.e

> Dataframe cached =CreateDataframeFromCache(my_cache).cache()

then use the cached Dataframe to **Join** by your key.

If your cache is really small I would also recommend to read about broadcast variables:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can group entries by a key that forces groups of 30 entries, then run for-each on the RDD of those groups.

As an example:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Long> numbers = 
         sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5, ..., 99))
           .zipWithIndex();
            //Adding an index as your data may not necessarily be ints
```

Now create a key that splits RDD into groups of 30 (roughly):

```
long count = numbers.count();
long remDiv = count/30; //long division

JavaPairRDD<Long, Iterable<Integer>> groupsOf30 = numbers
            .mapToPair(number -> new Tuple2<>(number._2 % remDiv, number._1 ))
            .groupByKey();
```

The above pair RDD essentially allows you to process groups of 30 with the `RDD.foreach` method:

```
groupsOf30.foreach(tuple -> {
    //Here, you should be able to process the iterable in one go...
    tuple._2 is an iterable of about 30 records
});
```